# prolog check element existence in list

Tags: list, prolog, element

for the question
"how to check if the 3 is member of a list" I defined the follow predicate

```
member(E,[E|_]).
member(E,[_|R] :- member(E,R).

isthreeinlist(L) :- member(3,L).
```

but how to "check whether 3 OR 4 is member of a list"?

any hint?

(3 AND 4 is easy though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;/2
```

is or predicate in prolog, check for description [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3B%29/2)

for example

```
threeorfor(X):- member(3,X); member(4,X).
    threeorfor([1,2,5]).
false

threeorfor([1,2,3]).
true
false
threeorfor([1,2,4]).
true
```